# the proof of the measurability of a sequence of monotone functions.

Tags: measure-theory

> [image]

I understand that $E_{kn}$ is disjoint and the union of $E_{kn}$ is equal to $X$. But, I don't understand that the next sentence "If we define $\varphi_n$ to be equal to $k2^{-n}$ on $E_{kn}$, then $\varphi_n$ belongs to $M(X, \mathbf{X})$".
Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: $\phi_n$ is the sum of multiples ($k 2^{-n}$) of characteristic functions of measurable sets ($E_{kn}$). The characteristic functions are measurable, multiples of measurable functions are measurable and sums of measurable functions are measurable.

Answer (score 1):

The whole construction of $\phi_n$ boils down to:$$\phi_n(x):=\min\left(2^{-n}\lfloor2^nf(x))\rfloor,n\right)$$
It is immediate that for every $n$ the image of the function $\phi_n$ is finite.

Then if $I$ denotes the image of $\phi_n$ for every element $p\in I$  the set $\phi^{-1}(\{p\})$ is measurable.

We have:$$\phi_n=\sum_{p\in I}p1_{\phi^{-1}(\{p\})}$$where $I$ is finite and the sets $\phi^{-1}(\{p\})$ are measurable, are disjoint and cover $X$.

Note that the inverse image of every set wrt $\phi$ is a finite union of measurable sets of the form $\phi^{-1}(\{p\})$ hence is measurable.

This makes clear that such a function is measurable.